# gsub replace pattern with backspace

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data set with a column that contains a label with the year (`OldLabel`), and I want to make another column that contains only the label, not the year (`NewLabel`). I wrote the following code, but it leaves a space at the end of the new labels.

```
data["NewLabel"] <- gsub("20..", "", data$OldLabel)
#removes any part of the OldLabel column that starts with 20 and ends with 2 digits, e.g: 2011 or 2008
```

Is there a way to have gsub replace the sequence with a backspace, so it gets rid of any spaces around the year it replaces? I tried using `"\\b"` as my replacement text, but that just replaced it with `b`, not a backspace.

EDIT: Per request, an example of `OldLabel` would be `"Valley Summer 2014"`, which should become `"Valley Summer"`, but ends up being `"Valley Summer "` with my current code. However, some might also be of the form `2012 Valley Summer`, so I don't think simply including a space in the pattern would be robust enough.

Comment: It would help to see some examples of `OldLabel`. If you want to replace "20" + "2 more digits", a better regular expression is "20\\d{2}".

Comment: or `gsub("20\\d\\d", "", data$OldLabel)` which shows very clearly the two digits being represented in the pattern, which is not as elegant as @neilfws.

Comment: I'll use the suggestion from @ShawnMehan to maintain readability. Thank you both though, it is a more robust and elegant pattern than what I had.

Comment: Also see `trimws`, which removes white space at the beginning or end of a string. You can wrap the output of `gsub` with this function if desired, though writing a smarter regex as 42- suggests is probably a better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data["NewLabel"] <- gsub("\\s*[0-9]\\s*", "", data$OldLabel)
```

Comment: This still leaves a space after the part that it removes. Could you explain your answer a little? What is `"\\1"` supposed to be doing?

Comment: This is probably what you want, remove any digits with optional space(s) on either side.

Comment: please try the new option.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `\\s*` on either side of my pattern is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This will not restrict its modifications to 4 -digit strings but will remove every digit: single, pairs, triplets, and years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 data["NewLabel"] <- gsub("[ ]{0,1}20[[:digit:]]{2}[ ]{0,1}", "", data$OldLabel)
```

The paired curley-braces are repetition quantifiers that have a range determined by either one (exact) or two (min and max) values. See `?regex` for more details. (You don't want to replace them with backspace characters.)

```
test <- c("2012 Valley Summer", "Valley Summer 2014")
gsub("[ ]{0,1}20[[:digit:]]{2}[ ]{0,1}", "", test)
#[1] "Valley Summer" "Valley Summer"
```

Comment: Your assumptionare about how gsub works are the problem. I say again (and now demonstrate with your amended example) ... you DON'T need a backspace

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you for clarifying. I should have read your answer more carefully. For posterity, I ended up with the following, which is a bit of a combination of your answer, Aidan Gawronski's answer, and Shawn Mehan's comment:
`data["NewLabel"] <- gsub("\\s*20\\d\\d\\s*", "", data$OldLabel)`